# Reusing validation conditions in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I like the granularity of Angular's form validation states, but it can get a little clunky when you have a form with lots of fields- even two fields start to make your markup a little soggy. Take the following example snippet:

```
<form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && vm.submit()">
    <div>
        <input type="text" required id="username" name="username" ng-model="vm.username" />
        <div ng-show="(myForm.username.$touched || myForm.$submitted) && myForm.username.$invalid">
            <!--various validation messages here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" required id="email" name="email" ng-model="vm.email" />
        <div ng-show="(myForm.email.$touched || myForm.$submitted) && myForm.email.$invalid">
            <!--various validation messages here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to do something more like the following?

```
<form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && vm.submit()">
    <div>
        <input type="text" required id="username" name="username" ng-model="vm.username" />
        <div ng-show="shouldShowValidationMessagesFor(myForm.username)">
            <!--various validation messages here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" required id="email" name="email" ng-model="vm.email" />
        <div ng-show="shouldShowValidationMessagesFor(myForm.email)">
            <!--various validation messages here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I believe that `$invalid` only triggers after `$touched`, so you should be able to just take out `$touched` and `$submitted`.

Comment: Also look into the `$error` property of angular forms.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg That's not the case. Elements that don't pass validation on page load start out as invalid. If you don't want to show error messages you use $untouched/touched/pristine/dirty. Regardless, that's not the point I'm getting after here. Reusability of whatever condition you set is what I think would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a method in your controller as you suggest:

```
$scope.shouldShowValidationMessagesFor = function (field) {
  var form = $scope.myForm;
  return (form[field].$touched || form.$submitted) && form[field].$invalid;
};
```

In your view, just pass in the field name you need validated according to the above logic.

```
<form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && vm.submit()">
    <div>
        <input type="text" required id="username" name="username" ng-model="vm.username" />
        <div ng-show="shouldShowValidationMessagesFor('username')">
            <!--various validation messages here-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" required id="email" name="email" ng-model="vm.email" />
        <div ng-show="shouldShowValidationMessagesFor('email')">
            <!--various validation messages here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below working demo [angular 1.3 required]

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.shouldShowValidationMessagesFor = function(form, field) {

    return ((field.$touched || form.$submitted) && field.$invalid);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && vm.submit()">
      <div>
        <input type="text" required id="username" name="username" ng-model="vm.username" />
        <div ng-show="shouldShowValidationMessagesFor(myForm,myForm.username)">
          <!--various validation messages here-->Unvalid username
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="email" required id="email" name="email" ng-model="vm.email" />
        <div ng-show="shouldShowValidationMessagesFor(myForm,myForm.email)">
          <!--various validation messages here-->Unvalid Email
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
```